# npm not found on Docker build

Tags: docker, github

I have very limited coding skills. I'm Trying to build a program named **Tabbycat** in Docker. for that I installed docker and then I executed a file named **windows_docker_start.bat** given within the program in bin folder. Here are the build logs:

```bash
# transferring context: 158.13kB                                                                              0.5s
# CACHED [web  2/14] RUN apt-get update                                                                          0.0s
# CACHED [web  3/14] RUN apt-get install -y curl nginx                                                           0.0s
# CACHED [web  4/14] RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -                                 0.0s
# CACHED [web  5/14] RUN apt-get install -y nodejs                                                               0.0s
# CACHED [web  6/14] RUN mkdir /tcd                                                                              0.0s
# CACHED [web  7/14] WORKDIR /tcd                                                                                0.0s
# CACHED [web  8/14] ADD . /tcd/                                                                                 0.0s
# CACHED [web  9/14] RUN git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://                                     0.0s
# CACHED [web 10/14] RUN pip install pipenv                                                                      0.0s
# CACHED [web 11/14] RUN pipenv install --system --deploy                                                        0.0s
# ERROR [web 12/14] RUN npm ci --only=production                                                                 0.4s
------
 > [web 12/14] RUN npm ci --only=production:
0.381 /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm ci --only=production" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
```

how can I fix this error? There is a similar question in StackOveflow and someone advised,

> Try installing npm separately

But How do I do that? I'm running a .bat file, please someone help me

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  The actual Dockerfile will be much more interesting than the build log.  Seeing both `pipenv` and `npm` in the same build stage is a little surprising; can you use a dedicated build stage `FROM node:12` to run the `npm` commands?

Comment: @DavidMaze it's from an upstream project and the Dockerfile is _intersting_ https://github.com/TabbycatDebate/tabbycat/blob/develop/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the build logs, it seems that you haven't had npm on the build environment. There should be nothing to be done to the bat file and only the Dockerfile should be changed.

You should change `RUN apt-get install -y nodejs` to `RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm`

Source: [phoenixNAP](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/npm-command-not-found#ftoc-heading-6)

Answer (score 0):

If something breaks, it's always worth to take a look to chase that down.
You are trying to execute `windows_docker_start.bat` now, what is that actually doing? If you check out the file [on GitHub](https://github.com/TabbycatDebate/tabbycat/blob/develop/bin/windows_docker_start.bat) you can see that this is actually just a `docker-compose` command.

If you didn't change anything, you can find the compose file it's trying to run [on GitHub](https://github.com/TabbycatDebate/tabbycat/blob/develop/docker-compose.yml) as well. As you can see, it's instructed to run a postgresDB as well as build two images from the local directory. You can now try to run the build buy hand to reproduce:

```
docker build -t tabbvycat-fail:latest .
```

*or* you can check the commit history and find that there's been an issue with the `npm` installation in the past that has been [fixed](https://github.com/TabbycatDebate/tabbycat/pull/2314).
Hence, if you upgrade to the latest version by pulling from GitHub your issue will go away. Note that the current [latest release](https://github.com/TabbycatDebate/tabbycat/releases) as of writing this comment, does not include this fix.